# DNS resolving is slow only when using cURL to fetch data

Tags: linux, networking, domain-name-system, bind

I have domain 'engine02.prod.qc.offercal.com' in my local `bind9`.

I don't think it's DNS server or TTL issue, because the benchmark is almost always look like this (I tried for 2 minutes using each method) :

```
curl -o /dev/null http://engine02.prod.qc.offercal.com:49157/void

        time_namelookup:  0.150
           time_connect:  0.151
     time_starttransfer:  0.152
                        ----------
             time_total:  0.152

curl -o /dev/null http://192.168.100.10:49157/void # use IP directly

                  time_namelookup:  0.000
           time_connect:  0.002
     time_starttransfer:  0.003
                        ----------
             time_total:  0.003

time dig @192.168.100.4 engine02.prod.qc.offercal.com

        real 0m0.009s
        user 0m0.004s
        sys  0m0.004s

time host engine02.prod.qc.offercal.com

        engine02.prod.qc.offercal.com has address 192.168.100.10
        real    0m0.011s
        user    0m0.006s
        sys     0m0.004s
```

My `resolv.conf` file:

```
[root@gateway01 ~]# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 192.168.100.4
```

I have been struggled with this issue for sometime, please help :D

Comment: How about use strace with timestamps enabled to see where curl is spending those 0.15 seconds `strace -tt -f curl -o /dev/null http://engine02.prod.qc.offercal.com:49157/void`

Comment: is 192.168.100.4 your resolve3r configured on this host ? dig test would be more accurate with default resolver. Furthermore, it's possible that curl makes first query, then the result is served from cache whan you issue dig. Repeat the test issuing each time `rndc flush` on the resolver, if possible.

Comment: This is interesting, I am having the *exact* same problem with centos7 and curl takes the same 150ms to do name lookups while dig is fast

Answer (score 5):

I just hit this issue recently while building updown.io and investigated it a bit (thanks @Dan for the `strace` command). Here is what I found:

## Condition

In my case curl was sometimes taking 65ms to resolve and sometimes <5ms.
It seemed to take 65ms after short time of inactivity (couple minutes) and <5ms after repeated calls. Definitely sounds like a cache and TTL issue obviously.
But my record has a 86400s TTL (1day) and it was already cached on my local resolver and dig always took 1ms.

## Measures

So I tried running curl with `strace` to see where the time was spend, and this is what I found (stripped some details for clarity):

```
05:57:52.303 connect(3) = 0
05:57:52.303 sendmmsg(3, ["1\26\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\22jarthon-architecte\3"..., "\0253\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\22jarthon-architecte\3"...] , 2) = 2
05:57:52.303 poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 1
05:57:52.303 ioctl(3, FIONREAD, [56]) = 0
05:57:52.303 recvfrom(3, "1\26\201\200\0\1\0\1\0\0\0\0\22jarthon-architecte\3"...) = 56
05:57:52.304 poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 4999) = 1
05:57:52.373 ioctl(3, FIONREAD, [96]) = 0
05:57:52.373 recvfrom(3, "\0253\201\200\0\1\0\0\0\1\0\0\22jarthon-architecte\3"...) = 96
05:57:52.373 close(3) = 0
```

This is DNS resolution part, what we can clearly see here is that 2 messages a sent, one response is received pretty quickly, and another one is received after a 69ms delay. I thought this second response is probably the IPv6 query (AAAA) so I tried it in dig:

```
$ dig AAAA jarthon-architecte.com

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
jarthon-architecte.com. 180 IN  SOA ns0.dnsmadeeasy.com. dns.dnsmadeeasy.com. 2008010120 43200 3600 1209600 180

;; Query time: 86 msec
;; SERVER: ::1#53(::1)
```

Ok there's no answer obviously, but this SOA record has a 180s TTL, this looks very like the time it took to go from 5ms to 65ms in my curl tests.

## Explanation

The SOA record is returned by your DNS server when there's no answer and contains among other things the negative TTL (last number on the line you can see 180) which is the time any resolver is allowed to cache negative responses (absence of record). So this means that when you query for the AAAA record, you have to hit the DNS server at least every 3 minutes just to make sure it's still not there.

## Fix

1. Add an IPv6 ☺
2. If you're managing the DNS the easiest fix is to increase this value, in my case I'm using DNSMadeEasy, I can create a custom SOA record with a higher TTL value and assign it to my domains: http://help.dnsmadeeasy.com/managed-dns/records/soa-start-authority-record/. This will make curl resolve faster most of the time, back to the level of performance we have on our properly cached A record.
3. If you're the one making the curls but don't manage the DNS, there are probably ways to optimize this at the DNS resolver level by serving stale negative response while fetching the real values or things like that, but I haven't looked into that yet.
4. If you're don't care about IPv6 you can also disable it using `curl` command line flag `-4`

Answer (score 1):

If this is a newer version of debian (namely ubuntu 13+) you need to have your dns-nameservers appended to the end of /etc/network/interfaces after your static ip config.  Editing resolv.conf will only bring you grief on these flavors of linux.

ie.

after gateway line

dns-nameservers local.dns.ip.here outside.back.ip.here